# Element's max-width 50% of parent's max-width?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I'm personally using React with `styled-components`, but this is a CSS/HTML problem. Here's my simple HTML structure:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

The parent `div` has a `max-width` of `1024px;`. I'm using `styled-components` for this, but that shouldn't matter:

```js
const Parent = styled.div`
  max-width: 1024px;
`;
```

And now I want to set my child width's `max-width` to 50% of the parent's *`max-width`*:

```js
const Child = styled.div`
  max-width: 512px;
`;
```

This works flawlessly, but I was wondering if it's possible to achieve the same result dynamically, i.e. something like:

```css
max-width: %parent.max-width / 2;
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but you get the idea.

The reasoning for my wish is that if I ever change my parent's `max-width` from `1024` to something else, I then have to manually go through all the children and adjust those too. In a simplified example like this it's clearly not an issue to change one number, but in a real project with hundreds of styles it becomes a burden.

I'd prefer not to use React or JS for this, other than what `styled-components` supports. Ideally I was hoping this could be done in CSS or SASS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you define parent's width as a constant :

```js
const parentWidth = 1024;
```

and then use it for both parent and child styled-components :

```js
const Parent = styled.div`
  max-width: ${parentWidth}px;
`;

const Child = styled.div`
  max-width: ${parentWidth / 2}px;
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using this calc css property like this

```
const Parent = styled.div`
  max-width: 1024px;
`;

const Child = styled.div`
  max-width: calc(100% / 2);
`;
```

Comment: Good idea, but it highly depends on the DOM structure and can be easily broken I guess.

Comment: CSS always depends on DOM structure, we always write css according to the DOM structure as it's indeed the stylesheet for it.
And it's never good practice to hard-code the width by a js variable I think

Comment: It's not the point, of course CSS depends on the DOM.
I meant **your solution** highly depends on the DOM, it can be easily broken if child has absolute position for example or any other styling that would cause `calc` to return an undesired value.
Of course using js variables to keep track styling values is a good practice since you can centralize your layout default values and make sure you always reuse the correct ones (also, that's how breakpoints are usually defined)

Answer (score 0):

I am not well educated with regards to react, however this is the raw CSS that achieves what you are looking for dynamically.

```
<div style="position:relative;">
   <div style="display:inline-block; width:50%;">
   </div>

   <div style="display:inline-block; width:50%;">
   </div>
</div>
```

So if you do this with the styled components:

```
const Parent = styled.div`
  max-width: 1024px;
  position: relative;
`;

const Child = styled.div`
  max-width: 50%;
  display:inline-block;
`;
```